# Reference a method (for use in a lambda) with specified parameters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a method to validate no negative numbers in `List` of numbers:

```
private void validateNoNegatives(List<String> numbers) {
    List<String> negatives = numbers.stream().filter(x->x.startsWith("-")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!negatives.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("negative values found " + negatives);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use a method reference instead of `x->x.startsWith("-")`? I thought about `String::startsWith("-")` but is not working.

Comment: I doubt it is possible to get an "applied" method reference, but you could create the lambda prior and merely supply it as an argument.

Comment: Not the question you asked, but you could do this test more simply using `noneMatch`. For example, `numbers.stream().noneMatch(x -> x.startsWith("-"));`

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't use a method reference because you need to provide an argument, and because the `startsWith` method doesn't *accept* the value you're trying to predicate. You could write your own method, as:

```
private static boolean startsWithDash(String text) {
    return text.startsWith("-");
}
```

... then use:

```
.filter(MyType::startsWithDash)
```

Or as a non-static method, you could have:

```
public class StartsWithPredicate {
    private final String prefix;

    public StartsWithPredicate(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public boolean matches(String text) {
        return text.startsWith(text);
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
// Possibly as a static final field...
StartsWithPredicate predicate = new StartsWithPredicate("-");
// Then...
List<String> negatives = numbers.stream().filter(predicate::matches)...
```

But then you might as well make `StartsWithPredicate` implement `Predicate<String>` and just pass the predicate itself in :)